# Go project workspace (Goland) of a library package behaves differently in Windows and Linux

Tags: go, goland

I am trying to create a new library package project using Go, but I am struggling to make the project setup work and make the workspace behave equally in my `Windows` and `Linux` environments. I created a new folder and used the `go mod init myname/mypackage` command to set up a new Golang project.

My `go.mod` file looks as follows:

```golang
module myname/mypackage
go 1.20
```

I intend to create a library project that has a set of sub-packages, so I did not add a `main.go` file defining a `main` package. I have added a bunch of sub-folders with Go files to lay out my library package structure. Each sub-folder represents a sub-package (at least, this is what I try to accomplish), so all code files within a sub-folder share the same package name.

Now, the compiler complains that there is no main package, and I have no clue how to configure it correctly. The subfolders also hold tests, which I can execute in my Linux environment right from within the Goland IDE.

**Update**

This is the folder hierarchy of my library package project; the `mypackage` folder is the repository root, which does not contain any Go files.

```
mypackage/
  go.mod
  build/
  sub_package1/
    module1.go
    module1_test.go
  sub_package2/
    module2.go
    module3.go
```

When I run the `go build -o build/` command, I receive the following error: `no Go files in <mypackage-path>`.

Aside from the compiler error, in my Windows environment, the Goland workspace seems to have issues resolving dependencies: My library package references external packages that get properly resolved in my Linux environment. The referenced packages are common and work without issues in my other non-library packages and apps; interestingly, Visual Studio Code provides code completions, but JetBrains Goland does not.

Comment: `replace` is not used to set the version of the current module. `go build` will not look tor a `main` package.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I am keen to learn how to set the version number correctly.

Comment: This might help: https://go.dev/doc/modules/version-numbers  there are many other online resources as well

Comment: The module version is metadata about a module, it is not located in the module's `go.mod` itself. The most common way to declare a version is via a tagged commit in your vcs (though there are other ways https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Remote_import_paths)

Comment: Yes better to use path like this ```/Users/name/go/src/github.com/username/package```

Comment: @MandeepGill, I don't know why you are suggesting that path, but that would be within the default GOPATH which _cannot_ be used with a module.

Comment: I am using the repo_url path for 2 years without any issue and the best thing is caching, any problem just remove the GOPROXY to direct works great.

Comment: if you go to GOPATH and see there is a default-src folder and this is the best location to store files as there are packages and a bin directory to install go compiles. not sure why you create a separate path. even in golang it is easy assessable GOPATH rather then other specific paths when you embedding files or assets into compiled files.

Comment: @JimB Or maybe i don't get you, what you saying.

Comment: @JimB I am talking about this ```https://go.dev/doc/modules/managing-dependencies#naming_module``` it helps to manage dependencies for others.

Comment: @MandeepGill. No, `GOPATH/src` should absolutely not be used, is deprecated, and incompatible with modules. Nowhere in the modern documentation does it say to use that directory. I don’t know how you are making use of it, but you have either changed GOPATH or are not actually using modules. You also should not name your module after a local absolute file path,

Comment: @JimB Yes not sure but I haven't changed the GOPATH and using modules too, can you please share any helpful links?

Comment: @MandeepGill, it’s all covered in the official docs, like https://go.dev/doc/code, or see the module reference for more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a library package project in Go, you don't need to have a main package or a main.go file. The main package is only required for executable programs.

To set up your library project correctly, follow these steps:

1. Create a new folder for your project. Let's say the folder name is "mypackage".
2. Open a terminal and navigate to the "mypackage" folder.
3. Run the following command to initialize a new Go module:

   ```
   go mod init myname/mypackage
   ```

   This will create a go.mod file in the "mypackage" folder.
4. Now you can start creating your library packages by organizing your code into sub-folders. Each sub-folder should represent a separate package.

   For example, you can have a structure like this:

   - mypackage

     - subpackage1

       - file1.go
       - file2.go
     - subpackage2

       - file3.go
       - file4.go

   Make sure that the package declaration at the top of each Go file matches the sub-folder name. For example, if you have a file1.go in subpackage1, the package declaration in that file should be `package subpackage1`.
5. You don't need to use the `replace` directive in your go.mod file for versioning unless you want to replace a dependency with a local copy during development. If you just want to use strict versioning, you can remove the `replace` directive from your go.mod file.

Your go.mod file should look similar to this:

```
module myname/mypackage
```

Make sure to replace `myname/mypackage` with the actual name of your package.

6. To use your library package in another project, you can import it using the module path specified in your go.mod file.

That's it! You have set up your library package project in Go. Remember to organize your code into separate packages within sub-folders, and ensure that the package declarations in your Go files match the sub-folder names.

Comment: Except for the `replace` in the `go.mod` file, this is exactly what I did. Should `go build` complete without any errors? I mean, I have tests in that project as well, and I am able to run them via `go test`.

Comment: I have updated my question; you may want to update/merge your answers. It still does not work, and the workspace behaves differently from what I know from Go projects having a main module.